# react developer tool incorrect state

Tags: reactjs

I am using react developer tool in my browser and I dont know why its not showing the correct values. I tried console.log and in my console it shows the correct value.

I got this code

```
 axios.all(promisesChoices).then(() => {
  console.log(Choices);

  self.setState({ Choices });
  console.log(self.state.Choices);
});
```

and it shows

[image]

but on my react dev tool

[image]

Anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async, so if you want to verify that it worked correctly, you can do so in its calllback function:

```
axios.all(promisesChoices).then(() => {
  console.log(Choices);

  self.setState({
    Choices
  }, () => {
    console.log(self.state.Choices);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and I got the value I was expecting, But still not updated in my dev tool, it still says empty array. Should I reinstall it? I tried to use it on that state and on my code it was able to get the correct values

Comment: I think you're just inspecting the value in the devtools at the point when it's not yet updated on the state.

Comment: hmm I got that code in my cdm and thats the only part of my code that set the state of my Choices. Plus I tried typing in $r.state.Choices and it shows the correct value